# Using period / dot when searching users by email on Microsoft Graph API and ODATA return no results

Tags: character-encoding, odata, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to get all users from my directory that have their email address starting with a given value.

All is working well except when my value contains a period / dot. In this case, the Graph API returns no result.

How can I search all users with their email starting by a given value containing a period / dot.

Here's an example.
The following request works fine:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(displayName, 'john')
```

The following request (containing a dot in the odata query) returns no results

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(displayName, 'john.d')
```

I already tried to encode the dot / period with %2E and it does not work:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(displayName, 'john%2ed')
```

Does anybody know how I can do that ?
Thanks !

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, dot should work in this filter query.

If we want to search the users by email. we could $filter the field `mail` not the field `displayName`.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(mail, 'john.d')
```